# Is custom sorting pattern possible in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose values are suppose

`c,d,b,a`

I want to sort the values except `'a'`. It should always be at the bottom. The order should be

`b,c,d,a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table1
order by val = 'a', val
```

Comment: You forgot to order secondarily by val.

Comment: @hatchet Hi you are right. I have added the secondary sort

Answer (score 5):

You can use a case statement to do this:

```
select * from table1
order by case when val = 'a' then 1 else 0 end, val
```

This will sort all values that are not 'a' before 'a', and then by the value.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e386c/1)

As pointed out by Mr Zorn in a comment, and by Luke101 in another answer this statement can be simplified as:

```
select * from table1
order by val = 'a', val
```

The former solution should work across all ANSI compliant databases, the latter works in MySQL, Postgresql and some others (but not MSSQL for instance).

Comment: The case statement is unnecessary and just adds complexity to the query, you should just be able to `order by value = 'a', val`

Comment: @MrZorn Indeed. I've updated the answer to reflect this, however I wanted to leave my original solution in.

Answer (score 0):

First select the columns from table which `NOT IN` `a` and the sort those values and then `UNION` the `a` column.

### **Query**

```
SELECT t.name FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM tbl
  WHERE name NOT IN ('a')
  ORDER BY name
)t
UNION 
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE name IN ('a');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f9aff3/1)**

Comment: While this might seem to return the desired result I would guess that it's not guaranteed to work as sets are normally unordered unless an order by clause is provided. It might be that MySQL makes it work though.

Comment: @jpw: Please check the fiddle demo

Comment: I agree with jpw. It seems you're counting on undefined behavior that happens to give the right results now. But if you were to make a change in the future (maybe add an int id column and make the clustered index on it), then it may mysteriously stop working the way you want.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't give the correct results, just that it probably happens by chance (or by the order rows are stored in the db), but I could be wrong.

Comment: MySql docs on UNION: "However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because **UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows**." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html